# Making a Pyramids card game, unsure of how to setup the pyramid

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I don't normally make games in PHP, I usually just do websites but I've made a card game in PHP before.

This time I wanted to attempt a pyramid solitaire game as I enjoy playing it.

I am unsure of how to go about setting up the initial pyramid (bottom front row revealed, rest tuned over).

Example: http://www.playjava.com/images/pyramids_ttl.jpg

[image]

I have made the pyramid using for loops and it sets it all up nicely, but my issue is I'm not sure if this will work for what I need or how to perform a check to see if a new card needs revealing.

I've usually got an idea of how things work in mind, but this has me stumped.

This is the for loop for the bottom row of 10 revealed cards. ($deck is an array of a ready shuffled deck.)

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $card = array_shift($deck);
    echo "<div style='position:absolute;top:".$card_lvl_1t.";left:".$card_lvl_1l.";width:55px;height:90px;'><img src='".$card."' border='0'></div>\n";
    $card_lvl_1l = $card_lvl_1l+56;
}
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Sorry if this post is a little confusing or not well described, but basically all I'm asking is advice on what you would do.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle for this?

Comment: why would i need to set up a fiddle?

Comment: So what does the output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my thoughts are not complete, but this is how I would go about this and is at a high level on how everything would be handled. This would still need to be tweaked/finalized before any coding could be performed.

I would not use php only, jQuery would also be involved. Basic gameplay is that two cards have to equal 13 and then they remove. If the cards removed fully unhide a card, the card shows. Plus do not forget about the waste and draw pile. jQuery would call PHP and PHP would return as JSON.

### PHP

```
Game class (OOP)
 |- initialize that would randomize the placement of cards in the pyramid and draw pile
 |- draw pile
 |   |- cards put in draw pile in a order to call
 |- waste pile
 |   |- cards put in waste pile in a order to call
 |- evaluate cards (card1, card2)
 |   |- sometimes may be one card (King)
 |   |- This would evaluate if they equal 13 and if they are remove
 |   |- Call to check card above if fully uncovered (probably would give each card a cover of 1 or 2 (1 card removed, then cover would be 0.5 or 1)
 |   |- successful?? remove cards from deck variables
 |   |- return JSON to remove cards and flip card X (if value not already in page, pass card face value)
 |- evaluate cover (card)
 |   |- this would check to see if the card is fully uncovered and used by the above
 |- card face value
 |   |- this would return the card face value
 |   |- Ex: King of Hearts may be KH, H13, or similar
 |- score
 |   |- self explanatory, but used to keep score if wanted
 |- card movment
 |   |- self explanatory
```

There of course would be variables that would store any information as far as what was in the pyramid, draw, and waste piles or card information.

### jQuery

This would include the actual game setup, play, and output.

```
 Click
  |- Track 2 clicks in a row (within same div??)
  |   |- same card
  |   |   |- waste pile or pyramid card - do nothing
  |   |   |- draw pile - move card to waste pile
  |   |   |   |- ajax call to move card from draw -> waste
  |   |- different cards
  |   |   |- highlighting of cards clicked
  |   |   |- ajax call to check value in php file
  |   |   |- if successful in removing cards, display uncovered card if returned
  |   |   |- update score
  |- controls that do not require 2 clicks
  |   |- card is a king
  |   |- new game
  |   |- draw to waste pile button
  |   |- etc....
```